# Динамический массив. Добавление элементов в конец

Tags: c++

Помогите с реализацией. Я попытался создать класс с динамическим массивом.
чтобы можно было добавлять элементы в конец.

```
class DynArray {
private:
    int size;
    double *mass;
public:
    DynArray() : size(0), mass(0) {}
    void add(const double &num) {
        double *p=new double[size+1]; 
        memcpy(p,mass,sizeof(double)*size); 
        p[size]=num; 
        delete[] mass; 
        mass=p; 
        size++;
    }
    double get(const int &n) {
        return mass[n];
    }
    ~DynArray(){delete[] mass;}
};
```

Этот код полностью работает, меня интересует нет ли нигде утечки памяти?

Comment: Лучше объясните как у вас вообще компилится этот код, без объявления mass. и memcpy скорее всего будет быстрее чем цикл и главное короче. И второй цикл у вас полюбому выходит за пределы массива `p`, т.к. size вы увеличили на 1

Comment: это метод класса

Comment: И кстати, зачем тут вообще второй цикл. мне кажется `double *p=new double[size+1]; memcpy(p,mass,sizeof(double)*size); p[size]=num; delete[] mass; mass=p; size++;` как то проще и короче ...

Comment: что значит memcpy что она делает?

Comment: копирует область памяти указанного размера. т.е. она полностью идентична вашему первому циклу. копирует в `p` содержимое `mass`

Comment: Да, вы кстати уверены, что mass всегда существует. он не может в функцию придти пустым...

Comment: @j6wj1997 А можете привести весь код класса?

Comment: Могу. Если подскажете как вставить код на форум в нормальном видео... у меня не получается. а этот как то сделал чисто случайно

Comment: @Flowneee realloc не всегда совместим с new. на некоторых платформах у них могут быть разные менеджеры памяти выделяющие ее по разному. а раз тут делают `new`, подозреваю, что и в констракторе класса делают `new`

Comment: Скопируйте код из своего редактора, выделите и нажмите на кнопку `{}` в редакторе

Comment: Происходит ли утечка памяти после вызова метода add ? Ведь я не освобождаю память, выделенную под p

Comment: Зачем писать костыли, если есть стандартные классы? Для вашего случая это будет std::vector

Answer (score 1):

Утечек нет - вы верно применяете RAII: все, что вы выделяете, вы освобождаете в деструкторе.
Есть пару мелких замечаний - например, какой смысл в передаче

```
add(const double &num)
```

Проще и с тем же эффектом передавать просто `double`.

И - очень неэффективно постоянно выделять/освобождать память при каждом добавлении. Так у вас получается `O(n)` выделения/освобождения на элемент. Если, скажем, удваивать всякий раз при переполнении размер блока памяти (запоминая его емкость и фактическое наполнение) - количество выделений/освобождений памяти падает до `O(1)` на элемент...

И еще - у вас нет копирующего конструктора и оператора присваивания, так что при этих операциях сгенерированные проведут поверхностное копирование, и будет у вас проблема с двойным освобождением памяти. Это очень неприятно, так что надо либо писать свои, либо запретить их вообще!